# failed copy file from path using powershell

Tags: powershell, file, copy

I have this script:

```
$UserFile = Read-Host "Drag your file here"
Copy-Item -Path $UserFile -Destination .\input
```

I want user drag their file to console, so that the script can know the exact path of user file and copy user file to input folder. but i got this error

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"C' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item -Path $UserFile -Destination .\input
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("C:String) [Copy-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

UPDATE:
It getting more weird guys, i think there is something wrong with my machine, i try to run the code on VM, and the code run with ZERO problem, and there's something different between my machine and VM, when i drag the file in my machine it will write like this `"C:\path\to\my\file.something"` but when i do that on my VM it write `C:\path\to\my\file.something` without `"`

UPDATE:
I just realized that i use different file, the file that i try on my machine is have white spaces in it `file one.something` but file that i use on VM don't have space `file.something` but i've tried to run the code like this

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\path\to\my\file one.something" -Destination .\input
```

using `"` and it work. but that not what i want, i want user to drag their file no matter there is white space or not.

Comment: Are you sure about the destination path `.\input` ? If that is not the problem, try to remove all quotes and surrounding spaces from the filepath you receive and re-quote it. Then use `LiteralPath`:  `Copy-Item -LiteralPath ('"{0}"' -f $UserFile.Trim('" ')) -Destination .\input`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the -Prompt param

```
$UserFile = Read-Host -Prompt "Drag your file here"
*** drags file ***

Write-Host $Userfile ## should display the filepath
```

Comment: Whats the actual value of $UserFile?

Comment: Path to my file, something like this `"C:\path\to\my\file.something"`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this isn't an issue for you anymore and an extra " was entered into the terminal before dragging your file. For me, the code you've posted works without issue.

You might want to check out [Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"C' does not exist](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/70dc4aa4-e883-4896-a065-d927a1e55bb9/cannot-find-drive-a-drive-with-the-name-quotc-does-not-exist?forum=winserverpowershell) where the issue was the exact same thing.

Depending on the use of this script, you can trim/remove any characters before using and, in my experience, it is almost always better to use absolute paths instead of relative (here the ./input) unless you explicitly want to have the script be relative.

Comment: I tried to run the code like this: `Copy-Item -Path "<path to my file>" -Destination .\input` and that include `"` but it work with no issue. Actualy i don't know what the problem is, but i will update this post when i found a solution. thanks.

Comment: By design, spaces, in file names, field names, folder names,  etc., must be quoted; this is why they should be avoided, or spaces need to be replaced with an underscore, or the like. This is a Windows proper thing, not a PowerShell limitation.